# How can I ensure the correct behavior of tf.control_dependencies() when I am training a GAN-like graph with multiple networks?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I suppose I can summarize this question as, "How do I use Batch Normalization when I have two unique networks?"

I am training what is essentially a GAN, with both the discriminator and generator having Batch Norm layers. This is a little different because the networks both have their own loss function entirely separate from one another, unlike the normal GAN framework. The second network is basically just being used to measure "how wrong" the generator is in a task but they both should be updated completely independently of one another.

My networks are both defined on individual GPUs since they are quite large.

I place the networks on each GPU and assign the dependcies in the following bit of my code:

```
with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    pred = uNet2D(X, BETA[j], KERNEL_SIZE, is_training)
    cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.reshape(Y,[-1]),logits=tf.reshape(pred,[-1])))

    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=LR[i]).minimize(W*cost)    



with tf.device("/gpu:1"):
    attention = attentionNetwork(X_ATTN, BETA[j], KERNEL_SIZE, is_training)
    cost_d = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=Y_ATTN,logits=attention))

    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        optimizer_d = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.2*LR[i]).minimize(cost_d)
```

I am a little concerned about this however because my tensorboard graph image suggests that the output of uNet (my generator) is an input the gradients used to update attenteionNetwork (my discriminator).

Can anyone help me determine the proper way to structure these blocks? I'm also concerned by the fact that optimizing attentionNetwork requires me to include the placeholders defined in uNet2D() and cost on gpu:0.

Thanks! My Tensorboard graph is attached below.

[image]

Edit: When I run this without Batch Norm and thus without control_dependencies() I get a Tensorboard that looks like this, which I'm pretty sure is what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am considering that you are using the [tf.layers.batch_normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization) function, since you are adding the update operations from `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` as dependencies.

The problem with your code is that you define the dependencies that include the batch norm updates using the whole `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` collection. Whenever you create a batch norm layer with `tf.layers.batch_normalization`, the update ops for that layer is added to the `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` collection. Thus, in the first code block, which defines the uNet2D, the `optimizer` will have only the collection of batch norm updates for UNet2D as dependencies. But, when you create the attentionNetwork, more batch norm updates are added to `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS`. Therefore, the dependencies for the optimizer of the attentionNetwork actually include all batch norm updates, including the ones for the uNet2D model.

In order to solve that, you need to filter the batch norm updates for each model. If you are using scopes to create each model, for example, as in:

```
with tf.variable_scope('unet2d'):
    # ... creation of the model uNet2D..

with tf.variable_scope('attention_network'):
    # ... creation of the model attentionNetwork..
```

you can use the scopes to filter the batch norm updates for each model:

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, scope='unet2d')
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=LR[i]).minimize(W*cost, var_list=tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope='unet2d'))    


update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, scope='attention_network')
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    optimizer_d = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.2*LR[i]).minimize(cost_d, var_list=tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope='attention_network'))
```

One side note: make sure that the correct variables are used in the optimizers. Since you are not passing the variables to the parameter `var_list` in the minimization function, the model will actually collect all variables in the `tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` collection.

Answer (score -2):

switch to pytorch like everyone is doing, https://discuss.pytorch.org/ they even have forum where developers answer question.